# .com creates automated link in post

Tags: plugins, posts, links

In classic mode, if we write "example.com", it creates automated link like :

```
 <a class="vglnk" href="http://example.com" rel="nofollow">
     <span>example</span>
     <span>.</span>
     <span>com</span>
 </a>
```

**What I tried:**

- I searched about it and found that `class="vglnk"` comes from Discus
  Plugin and we need to disable an option to do that.  But it will affect another affiliate links so I could not proceed further. [image]
- I tried to search about HTML entity for 'dot'. so that we can use
  that sign so that wordpress does not take it as a link. But that sign
  converts into '.' itself
- I tried to add that link in `<!-- wp:html -->example.com<!-- /wp:html -->`..it did not work
- I tried to add `<pre>example.com</pre>` but still it is not working

I want plain text of example.com, please assist me.

Comment: Can you explain your first point? You said you found the setting in Disqus? Why can't you turn that off? What "basic operations' security"?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I've added image of the changes. 

But it will affect another affiliate links so I could not proceed further.

Comment: If your problem is directly related to the Disqus plugin, you'll likely need to go through their help articles or contact them for support. Or possibly research some alternative for your affiliate links that doesn't make it an all-or-nothing choice.